# React Navigation - Check on which screen the user is

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am using react-navigation in my project and I need to detect if the user is on the Dashboard/Graph/Posts page.

For example, if I am on Posts page, I need a param to write a conditional.

e.g. Make a request if I am only at Posts page

Is it possible to check on which screen the user is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get it through `navigation` object, try it

```
this.props.navigation.state.routeName
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following,

> on componentDidMount

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.subs = this.props.navigation.addListener("didFocus", payload => {
      console.log("PAY_LOAD...", payload);

     // Check the payload and your logic(you can get the current screen name like => payload.state.routeName)
    });
  }
```

> on componentWillUnmount

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    this.subs.remove();
  }
```

Note: Don't forgot to remove listener on 'componentWillUnmount()'